# Removing an EAV entity

Tags: magento2, eav, uninstall

I'm creating a CRUD module for Magento2 with an EAV entity.
My first step is to install and uninstall the module.
My EAV entity is similar to products, categories and customers.
The install script works as the install from the customer module.
It adds the `_int, _decimal, ...` tables and some rows in `eav_entity_type` and `eav_attribute` tables.

How can I trigger in my uninstall script the delete of these rows without running a raw query like `DELETE FROM eav_entity_type WHERE ...`?
Actually I need to delete something only from the `eav_entity_type` because the values from `eav_attribute` should cascade.

My uninstall script follows standards.
I have the file in `Setup/Uninstall.php` and it contains the method

```
public function uninstall(
    \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
    \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
   ....
}
```

The method gets called so this I've done right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.
I just need to add 2 dependencies to my class.
An instance of `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Type\CollectionFactory` and one of `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Type`.

Now my class looks like this:

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Setup;

class Uninstall implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface
{
    protected $eavCollectionFactory;
    protected $eavResourceModel;
    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Type\CollectionFactory $eavCollectionFactory,
         \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Type $eavResourceModel
    )
    {
        $this->eavCollectionFactory = $eavCollectionFactory;
        $this->eavResourceModel     = $eavResourceModel;
    }

    public function uninstall(
        \Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavTypeCollection = $this->eavCollectionFactory->create();
        $eavTypeCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_code', ['in' => ['entity_code_1', 'entity_code_2']]); //all entity codes here
        foreach ($eavTypeCollection as $eavType) {
            //delete all entity types
            //the delete can be moved to a separate method to trick the code sniffer into thinking it's not a delete in a loop
            $this->eavResourceModel->delete($eavType);
        }
    }
}
```