# Remove customer attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to remove customer attributes which are created during install 3rd party extention in magento 2?

Comment: You want to remove using code or directly in database.

Comment: Check this linkhttps://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209867/60921 it may be helpful

Comment: We add one extension which is we want remove fully; from files & also from database.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This :-**

```
namespace Company\Modulename\Setup 

class Uninstall implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface
{

    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
          $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function uninstall(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
         $setup->startSetup();
         $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();       
         $entityTypeId = 1; // Attributte Id
         $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'attribute_code');
         $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: We add 'https://github.com/amitshree/magento2-account-approval' this extention. in this only public function install; so we create one more function in 'InstallData.php' file ?

Comment: Create script in magento2-account-approval/Setup/Uninstall.php after that follow below command:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
php bin/magento cache:clear

Comment: When we add 'Uninstall.php' at that time any necessary to remove 'InstallData.php' 
 from 'magento2-customer-account-approval/Setup'  before command run ?

Comment: Not need to removed.

Comment: Thanks Very much. its working for us. We change some other things. add this Uninstall.php file then delete attribute from database. So my work is done as per our requirement.

Comment: If You found this answer is useful please approve this!! Thank you

Comment: Do you know why `$this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);` does not work on uninstall? Why is the parameter wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can create either an upgrade or install script in your custom module. Here an example with an install script:

```
<?php

 namespace vendor\module\Setup;

 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

 class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {
 private $eavSetupFactory;

 public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) 
 {
 $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
 }

 public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
 {

 $setup->startSetup();

 $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
 $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
 \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
 'custom_attribute');

 $setup->endSetup();

 }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. We add 'https://github.com/amitshree/magento2-account-approval' this extention. Please guide me what to do for it.

Comment: We want to remove this extention from our site. but in customer data value of attribute which is generated by this extention. so we remove all data and attribute which is generated by this extention.

Comment: We add 'public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
  
  $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
   $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'approve_account');

        $setup->endSetup();
    }' this code as your answer update but attribute not remove.

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124059/removing-an-eav-entity